# Difference between "clever" and "skillful"

Tags: differences, adjectives

What is the difference between *clever* and *skillful*?

Comment: Consult your local dictionary.

Comment: This question would probably not have been closed if there were some elucidated question about how you think they are the same or different.

Answer (score 5):

My first thought is that *clever* implies something done with the mind, whereas *skillful* implies something done with the hands.

You might have a *clever* algorithm, but a *skilled* sculptor.

A *clever* plumber may figure out a good way to route a pipe, particularly in a situation when there's no straightforward way to do it.  A *skilled* plumber will do a good job soldering the pipes together.

A *skilled* painter can paint the Mona Lisa.  A *clever* painter can make you wonder what she's smiling about.

I then checked an on-line dictionary, to confirm my initial hunch:

> **skilled** (adj.):  having or showing or requiring special skill ("*Only the most skilled gymnasts make an Olympic team*.")
>
> **clever** (adj.):  mentally quick and resourceful ("*You are a clever man; you reason well*.)

Not too bad, although it's worth noting *clever* had some secondary meanings I hadn't considered.  Clever readers will go investigate.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but I think tying "skill" to physical actions is a wrong move. One can be a "skilled teacher", but not be clever or physical.

Comment: Excellent point. I've described a trend, but, unsurprisingly, there are many counterexamples. A teacher can be skilled, and a fencer could exhibit clever swordsmanship. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Indeed, I think it's more of a scope issue. Skill is quite narrow in scope — it *tends* to deal in a specific aptitude for a specific task or set of tasks, and to be of a more formally obtained nature. Cleverness is much broader, being an attribute of the person themselves, and the way that it is applied to tasks and groups of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Clever implies nothing about the amount of effort expended, whereas skillful carries the connotation of having spent considerable time learning or practicing the activity concerned.

In general, cleverness is innate, whereas skills are learned.